Should I use volumes or bind mounts to avoid building a new Docker images for every application config file change?
I'm running bind9 in a Docker container (in a Linux VM) using a Dockerfile that contains these lines.
COPY configuration/named.conf /var/lib/bind/
COPY configuration/tzzz.yo.zone /var/lib/bind/
COPY configuration/10.168.192.in-addr.arpa /var/lib/bind/
COPY configuration/named.conf.options /var/lib/bind/

It works great. No complaints. No regrets . . . other than whenever I need to change a DNS record I need to build a new image.
For apps that require frequent config file updates which option is best, volumes or mounts? Performance is not a concern. I'm trying to streamline the change process.
Or perhaps I should create volumes when I build the image and then bind mount them when I run. probably.
I have not done a good job of mentally separating the Dockerfile build & config from the syntax of running a container based on the image.

Separate configuration and code.
Configuration should go in a volume. Images should be general. Consider the case of dynamic updates - if those are written into the image, they will be lost on upgrade of the image.
